# Best way to test mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-mock-store

I am writing tests to test mapDispatchToProps involving dispatch.

This is my mapDispatchToProps.

```
    export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        return {
            getListOfYears: url => dispatch(getListOfYears(url))
        };
    };
```

The method in dispatch is as follows.

```
    export const getListOfYears = url => {
        return getService(url, { actions: getActions(actionNames.GET_LIST_OF_YEARS), shouldRequest });
    };

    export const shouldRequest = () => {
        return true;
    };

    export const requestActionCreator = actionName => () => ({
        type: getRequestActionType(actionName)
    });

    export const failureActionCreator = actionName => error => ({
        type: getFailureActionType(actionName),
        payLoad: error
    });

    export const successActionCreator = actionName => response => {
        if (response && response.data && response.status === 200) {
            return {
                type: getSuccessActionType(actionName),
                payLoad: response.data
            };
        }
        return {
            type: getFailureActionType(actionName),
            payLoad: response
        };
    };

    export const getActions = actionName => ({
        requestAction: requestActionCreator(actionName),
        successAction: successActionCreator(actionName),
        failureAction: failureActionCreator(actionName)
    });

    export const getRequestActionType = actionName => `${actionName}_REQUEST`;
    export const getSuccessActionType = actionName => `${actionName}_SUCCESS`;
    export const getFailureActionType = actionName => `${actionName}_FAILURE`;
```

This is my test case in Jest.

```
    it('dispatches action getListOfYears', () => {
        mapDispatchToProps(dispatch).getListOfYears(mockUrl);
        expect(dispatch.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual(actions.getListOfYears(mockUrl))
    });
```

dispatch.mock.calls[0][0] gives me an anonymous function. Please advice on a way to test this.

Thanks.

Comment: well... why do you need to test mDTP? or better yet why use it at all, why not just use the `dispatch` injected when you `connect` the component? less boilerplate that way.

Comment: Can you show me an example on injecting dispatch when connecting?

Comment: you dont need to pass mapDispatchToProps, `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)`. Inside of the component you will have `this.props.dispatch`. its already injected when you `connect` it.